# rlwrap -z pipeto: piping output through pagers

Tags: command-line, pipe, colors, grc

I am using `rlwrap` to colorize prompt in asterisk `CLI`:

```
rlwrap -s 99999 -a -pRED /usr/sbin/asterisk -r
```

I read in `man rlwrap` that I can also use

```
rlwrap -z pipeto
```

to pipe output through a colorizer. I have `grc` colorizer which works like this:

```
cat foo | grcat <conf_file>
```

The above examples colorizes `foo` using the rules from `<conf_file>`.

**How can I use `rlwrap -z pipeto` to colorize output from `rlwrap` through `grcat` ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `pipeto`

Unfortunately, `rlwrap`'s built-in filter `pipeto` does not filter output in the way you desire. I find the documentation rather misleading, but what it does is if you run `rlwrap -z pipeto some-shell`, then, within the interaction:

- if you type commands without any pipe sign (`|`), those are passed verbatim to `some-shell` and then the output of that is simply printed;
- if you type `command | filter`, then `command` is passed to `some-shell` to interpret, and the output of that is piped through `filter` before being printed (where `filter` is any command you could run from the command line in your Unix shell).

So the good news is you could get the behavior you are looking of, kindof, sortof, by running `rlwrap -z pipeto asterisk` and then remembering to append `| grc` to each command you want to pass to asterisk. But that would not be very convenient, would it? Hence `outfilter`.

## `outfilter`

I suggest creating the following `rlwrap` filter script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use lib ($ENV{RLWRAP_FILTERDIR} or ".");
use RlwrapFilter;
use strict;

my $filter = new RlwrapFilter;
my $name = $filter->name;

my $filter_command = join ' ', @ARGV;

$filter->help_text("Usage: rlwrap -z '$name <filter-command>' <command>\n"
                   . "Filter <command> output through <filter-command>");

$filter->output_handler(sub {""});
$filter->prompt_handler(\&prompt);
$filter->run;

sub prompt {
    my $prompt = shift;

    my $output = $filter->cumulative_output;
    $output =~ s/\r//g;

    open (PIPE, "| $filter_command")
        or die "Failed to create pipe: $!";
    print PIPE $output;
    close PIPE;

    return $prompt;
}
```

Save it as `outfilter`, make it executable, and then run `rlwrap -z './outfilter <coloring-filter>' shell`. I tried with:

```
rlwrap -z './outfilter ccze -A' gosh
```

which nicely colors Gauche's output. In your case, that would become something like:

```
rlwrap -z './outfilter grcat grcat-config' asterisk
```

If you like the filter and want to be able to run it without having to specify its path, you could move it alongside the builtin filters (on my system, that's in directory `/usr/share/rlwrap/filters`).

Note that the filter as written is probably inefficient (it spawns a new copy of the coloring filter for each interaction with the command shell, because that's the shortest way I could find to have it flush its buffers) and fragile, but if the shell you are interacting with doesn't do any black magic of its own, it should work.

Comment: you beat me to the answer! I think that the _name_ `pipeto` is misleading, rather than its documentation, but it is too late to change the name now, I think. Any ideas about how to improve the documentation? I will probably add a slightly more efficient and robust version of your filter to `rlwrap`.

Comment: Hehe. I'll contribute a documentation pull request on GitHub when time permits. I learned more on `rlwrap`'s scriptability answering this question than in years of use :-). Let me know if you would like me to submit this filter as well, as a starting point.